# Illegal string offset 'id' while for loop php

Tags: php

i have this issue and i think is easy to fix for this but i can't handle how to do this ;x

EDIT: I'm know why im getting this error, $user->items[$i] is a string but still... idk how i can fix it

The part of code where im getting the error looks like this

```
                            for($i=0;$i <= 10; $i++){
                            if($user->items[$i]["id"] != $item->id){
                                $user->items = json_encode(array_merge($user->items, $drop_item));
                            } else {
                                $user->items = json_encode(array_merge($user->items[$i], ['amount' => 99]));
                            }
                        }
```

and when im running my code im gatting this error Illegal string offset 'id'

the array looks like this if it matters

```
[{"id":12,"amount":1,"upgrade":0},{"id":13,"amount":1,"upgrade":0}]
```

Comment: `$user->items[$i]` is a string not an array. Maybe its JSON...

Comment: Your JSON string is an array of objects, but your code is assuming an array of arrays. Perhaps you should post the code you used to decode the string.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular Sure, im doing somethink like this: `$user->items = json_decode($user->items, true);`

Answer (score 0):

On the first iteration of your loop you overwrite `$user->items` with a string (the result of `json_encode()`). On the next iteration it's no longer an array so you get an error message.

You're also assuming that there will always be exactly 10 items in the array. What if there aren't?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i type the 10items for example in my code im have somethink like this `$count_arr = count($user->items);   for($i=0;$i <= $count_arr; $i++)`,.